# Import FFmpeg into Audacity

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, audacity

I'm trying to import [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) into [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) (so I can encode AAC audio)

But the latest FFmpeg [Windows build](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) doesn't include the **avformat-55.dll** file I need. Where can I find this file, or is it not included anymore?

[image]

Comment: Tl;DR https://lame.buanzo.org/ffmpeg-win-2.2.2.zip has avformat-55.dll

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [FFmpeg project](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) recommends Windows builds from the following sources:

- https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/
- https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases

On one of these pages, select a “shared” build so the DLL will actually be there. It will be located in the “bin” folder. However, the current version is 57. It may or may not work with Audacity.

Also keep in mind to pick the correct choice from 32/64 bit: It needs to match Audacity’s “bitness”. You can look in Task Manager to find out whether it’s a 32-bit process.

**On the official Audacity wiki**, theres a [section on how to get FFmpeg](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_and_updating_audacity_on_windows.html#winff). It directs you to this page: http://lame.buanzo.org/#lamewindl You can find the required FFmpeg version there.

Downloads from that page are terribly slow, so I’ll provide a mirror: http://download.futuretech.in/ffmpeg-win-2.2.2.zip

Unfortunately, there’s no checksum on the original page, so I cannot prove that my mirror isn’t tampered with. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Ow I didn't know the "Shared" version included the DLLs. Audacity showed up as 32 bit in the task manager, and I tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions of FFmpeg's **avformat-57.dll** but that indeed didn't work. The version 55 DLL from **ffmpeg-win-2.2.2.zip** did work for me, thanks again

Comment: It happened to me (it might happen to newies as well) that I was downloading the upper links of the Official Audacity wiki (lame), instead of scrolling down to the lower links (ffmpeg) which are the necessary ones. Please notice!

Comment: Pls fix dead link `http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/`.

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2021, the official Audacity manuals' [instructions for Installing FFmpeg for Windows](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_ffmpeg_for_windows.html) advise downloading FFmpeg from [lame.buanzo.org](https://lame.buanzo.org/#lamewindl); scroll down the page and click the link "FFmpeg RECOMMENDED ZIP OPTION: ffmpeg-win-2.2.2.zip", unzip it in your desired location, then point Audacity to avformat-55.dll in the unzipped folder.